# iOS Auto layout in percentage

Tags: ios, autolayout

I wanna create  a   simple  iOS application using autolayout that   displays    three   UIViews.    One on  the top,    one on  the left    and 
the other   on  the right.  The top view    should  be  50  pixels  high    and fills   the horizontal  space completely.   The left    column  should  fill    40% of  the horizontal  space   and should  fill    100%    of  the 
vertical    space.  The right   column  should  be  60% of  the horizontal  space   and 100%    of  the vertical space. Finally in  the left    UIView  wanna add   a   single  button.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You can.

1. Add first view at the top, add four constraint, top 0 left 0 right 0 and height 50.
   [image]
2. Add second view at bottom of first view, make it top 0 left 0 heigth 100.
3. Here is the trick, choose first and secound view, then make them equal width.
4. Choose secound view's width constraint, and change the multiplier to 0.4.
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

The two existing answers didn't work for me. My answer was built using Xcode version 10.1 (10B61).

The core question is "How Can I Set a View’s Width to be a Percentage in a Storyboard". **Answer: the view's width needs to be associated with the superview.**

Explanation:

1. In the Main.storyboard (already containing a View Controller and a View), add a View. I’m going to call it YellowView). And change its containing view name to SuperView.
2. In the YellowView's Attributes Inspector change the Background to Yellow.
3. Click on New Constraints and Top = 0, Leading (left) = 0, height = 50
4. Control Drag from the YellowView to the Superview and let go, in the resulting dialog select "Equal Widths" [image: Figure 1]
   Note: YellowView's width becomes the width of the SuperView.
5. **In the Storyboard, Double-click the width constraint we just added and change the Multiplier to 0.25** (Note: Typing .25 will not work - the leading zero is necessary)

Answer (score 2):

Your constraints should be like,

**first view** - top,leading(left),trailing(right) and fix height

**left view** - top, left(leading), bottom and equal width with superview with multiplier 0.4 (or width constraint with 0.4 multiplier)

**right view** - top,right(trailing),bottom and equal width with superview with multiplier 0.6 (or width constraint with 0.6 multiplier)

hope this will help  :)